# Intellij removes tabs after reformatting code while using tab character

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using a licensed IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.1.

For one of my project I need to use `tabs` for indentation.
I create a new code style scheme containing:

- Use tab character: checked
- Smart tabs: unchecked
- Tab size: 4
- Indent: 4
- Continuation indent 8

Note that the project has an `.editorconfig` file but I disabled that plugin.

When I create a new class, the desired indentation (`tabs`) seems to work.

But as soon as I reformat the the code, `tabs` are replaced by `spaces`.

Maybe I'm missing some setting?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163294

Comment: You should just reformat the entire project to use spaces anyway. Tabs are antisocial and should really be refactored whenever possible.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Thanks for nothing (as I said I *need* to use tabs).